Is it reasonable to assume that “non-nom,” “nam-nam,” “num-nun,” etc. originated from Wolof?
In English there are words like:
num-num

(childish) Tasty food

nom

(colloquial) Used to denote eating, or enjoyment of eating. Commonly used as "nom nom nom".


The Wiki page on Wolof says:

English is believed to have adopted some Wolof loanwords, such as banana, via Spanish or Portuguese,[4] and nyam, used also in Spanish: 'ñam' as an onomatopoeia for eating or chewing, in several Caribbean English Creoles meaning "to eat" (compare Seychellois Creole nyanmnyanm, also meaning "to eat").

The connection between Wolof: ‘nyam,’ and Spanish: ‘ñam,’ especially with the semantic onomatopoeia for eating, makes it seem like the English counterparts listed above would have similar origins.
Is it reasonable to assume that “non-nom,” “nam-nam,” “num-nun,” etc. originated from Wolof?

I fail to see how Wolof and Spanish are related. Wolof and French would have a closer relationship than the former. Things can just appear on their own in languages without any reference to other languages. And in English, the usual word is yum-yum, not num-num. Onamatopeias are not usually "translinguistic".

Words like ‘om-nom-nom’ and ‘nyam’ are very likely to be onomatopoeia. They recreate the sound small children make if they vocalise when they eat (which children often do), before their parents teach them to eat with their mouths closed and not talk with their mouths full. Even languages like Vietnamese have very similar, and often reduplicated, expressions. That makes any origin as a loan word less likely.

@JanusBahsJacquet that would make a good answer.

@Lambie yum-yum is certainly the typical onomatopoeia for enjoying tasty food, but nom-nom isn't unusual either (wiktionary lists it as popularised online from 2007, albeit typically being spelt num-num until 2013)

@Tristan That changes nothing re the misguidedness of the question...Personally, I have never heard nyam-nyam except in French or om-nom-nom. In any event, they don't travel between languages.
